# Python: returning 'None' from a sub and printing return value

Tags: python

I have the python script below which returns a variable which can either be `None` or a blob of data read from a file. I thought this would be an easy way to determine one of three states:

- any error returns `None`
- empty data returns an empty variable
- successful read returns data in variable

This (also below) is the error I am getting.  I could just assign `""` to `data` instead of `None` and test for an empty variable but that seems a little cheesy. Printing the variable wrapped in `str()` might work but that seems like a lot of extra typing (or special function to print the variable) every time I want to print the variable. I must be waaayyy off base here.

```
$ ./foo.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 20, in <module>
    print " data read was " + line_read
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

def get_data (src):
   data = None

   if os.path.isfile (src):
      with open(src, 'rt') as f:
         data = f.read

   return data


line_read  = get_data('foo.txt')

if line_read is None:
   print "no data in file"
   sys.exit(1)

print " data read was " + line_read
```

Comment: `data = f.read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is you are using `f.read`. Python supports high-order programming, which in essence allows you to assign functions/method to variables. Then, what you are returning from `get_data` is basically a function which cannot be concatenated with a string which is the error you are getting, so to fix this call the method `read` as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

def get_data (src):
   data = None

   if os.path.isfile (src):
      with open(src, 'rt') as f:
         data = f.read() # this will solve your problem

   return data


line_read  = get_data('foo.txt')

if line_read is None:
   print "no data in file"
   sys.exit(1)

print " data read was " + line_read
```

Comment: Thanks. Totally missed the parenthesis :/

Answer (score 1):

You have just assigned variable `data` to a method with that `data = f.read` call, you should actually call that method with:

```
data = f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps add parenthesis from wherever you are calling a function. In your program,`f.read()` is a function but you typed it as `f.read` which causes the error. The solution is to **replace** `f.read` with `f.read()`.

Comment: how is this answer different from the existing ones?